# Нерабочий пример Android

Tags: android, button, listener

Изучал программирование под андроид, нашел вот такой интересный пример 
http://src-code.net/slushanie-modeli-programmirovanie-android/ Целую неделю с ним мучался, не мог понять почему не реагирует на нажатие кнопок. Может кто-нибудь поможет разобрать этот злополучный пример?

Comment: Не следует создавать вопрос, полностью повторяющий ранее заданный вопрос в такой формулировке. В вопросе должен быть конкретный вопрос в заголовке, минимальный воспроизводимый пример неработающего кода, должно быть показано что вы пытались сделать. Плюс, вопрос должен быть потенциально полезен кому-то ещё. Вопрос же вида "по ссылке есть код он у меня не работает" не несёт общественной пользы и может стать вовсе бесполезным если ссылка помрёт.

Comment: А вдруг кто-нибудь еще столкнется с этим? И не будет работать. Вот вам "полезен кому-то еще". И что мне скопировать и сюда вставить?

Comment: Я не знаю, что вам скопировать надо... Я на 95% уверен что это либо у вас где-то опечатка, либо с самом примере. Единственный подходящий вариант, как мне кажется будет такой - выложить весь код, коий у вас не работает на GitHub и в вопросе указать, что это вопрос по задаче из такой-то книги, с такой то главы, например. Так тоже будет не идеально... Но в нынешнем виде - вы вот сможете представить как человек должен искать в гугле решение решение аналогичной вашей проблемы так, чтобы попасть на этот именно вопрос в его текущей формулировке?

Comment: Думаю, вам надо не целиком взять этот пример, а разбить его на части - отображение точек отдельно, нажатие на кнопки отдельно. А потом попробовать соединить. А не пытаться найти ошибку в сложном для вас проекте.